# Postgis - Construct linestring of length N

Tags: postgis, linestring

Give a table of linestrings (roads)

ogc_fid, wkb_geometry

And a road with ogc_fid = X

In postgis how could I construct a linestring that is of length Y metres made up of roads starting from road X? I do not care which direction the line expands out of. It is important that the algorithm goes both ways to prevent dead ends.

My starter code was this:-

```
SELECT ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(R.wkb_geometry)) FROM ROADS R
WHERE ST_Touches(R.wkb_geomtry, (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM ROADS where ogc_fid = X))
```

But I am not on the right track as this returns a MultiLineString which means the LineMerge  has not worked?